# Biggest possible resolution or go for common denominator?

Tags: ffmpeg, television

I need to transcode 720p AVC videos to Xvid because they need to be played on a Samsung DVD player. The player can handle maximum 448 pixel high videos and automatically scales the picture up to 1080p for the full HD TV. Now the question is, should I downscale to 448p for the highest theoretical resolution or 360p because it's exactly 1/4 of the source's and 1/9 of the TV's resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried both and the empirical result is that the 360p video looks *much* better than the 448p. Even on my full HD computer screen played in VLC but on the TV screen it was definitely a lot better.
So in my experience the proportionate imaging is more important than the theoretical resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the player can rescale the video to Full HD fast enough, I would output to the highest resolution acceptable.